# What could cause a freshly formatted ext4 partitions to have wildly different used space?

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, gparted, ext4

I have four ext4 partitions on a newly *formatted* gpt disk. Eventhough I have no files in these partitions a lot of space is used up already.

Highlighted in blue is a partition that has less used space than a smaller partition right above it. What could cause this?

[image]

I've tried deleting and recreating the partitions, and even checking the disk for errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am going to guess that gparted includes the ext4 "root-only" reservation among used space.

In ext2/3/4, a certain amount of space (5% by default) is kept in reserve – processes without root privileges can only fill the disk up to 95%, at which point they start getting "no space" errors while privileged services can continue running just fine.

Because this space is unusable for regular users, it's likely that gparted just doesn't count it as "available" (as it isn't). You can adjust the reserve using `tune2fs -m 5 /dev/sdg3`.

In particular, if the filesystem is not shared between system and users (e.g. if it's a dedicated OS-only partition like /opt, *or* it's a dedicated user data partition like /home), then it is completely safe to disable the reservation (`tune2fs -m 0`).

Answer (score 0):

The file system needs to use some space to track your files. It depends on each type of FS, but a couple of things are bad sectors and the freespace table.

Also, it creates a few files at the root (`.`, `lost+found`, `..`, ...)

The root directory is also duplicated a certain number of times (you can tune that, although I never did, the defaults are generally just fine.) The duplicated sectors (such as your freespace table) are there to make sure that if one of the sectors that goes bad happens to be part of such a table, your file system continues to work.

These duplicates do not show up as files, but they are shown when you format the drive (usually). They give you the sector number and sizes, etc.

Comment: Still, nearly 500 MB out of a 12 GB partition? That's a whole 5%. It's _a lot_ more than would be expected for an empty filesystem's metadata. (Actually, it is _suspiciously_ close to the 5% "root-only" reservation that ext4 enables by default...)

Comment: @grawity, you're right, I did not calculate that... Old systems had problems with heads/cylinders and such, but I've seen such in ages and I would imagine the drive does not have that many bad sectors.